# Meaning of 'All-out brawl'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, american-english, british-english, adverbial-phrases

I know the meaning of 'brawl'.But what does this phrase 'all-out brawl' mean?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: All-out = "made with maximum effort" - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all-out

Comment: All out certainly means maximum effort but I have always interpreted this particular usage as meaning 'the inclusion of everyone'.  Typical early Western movie scene where everyone in the saloon is brawling en masse, except for one guy who is playing the piano amidst the chaos.

Comment: We also sometimes use out-and-out with the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone sir.